# Multiple verbs as noun modifiers

Tags: grammar, usage, verbs

I am trying to say something like "The button labeled 'blue' at the lower right is red."

I know that adjectives can be connected together with their て-form. It seems like maybe the the same should happen with verbs, but the ordering and sentence connection implied by the て-form makes this sound awkward to me. For some reason, I also cannot find examples on this.

The two verbs I am thinking of are ある and 付けられる (labeled?).

My current translation is 右下にあって「blue」と付けられたボタンは赤いです。

May someone explain how to connect with multiple noun-modifying verbs? Also, what is a natural translation for my example sentence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to when verbs are connected by the て form because you want to express that their tense is identical and the two or more verbs are connected in sequence.

りんごをあらってたべた。　I washed the apple and ate it.

but when verbs are used to modify a noun, you need the verb tenses to agree with the state of the thing they are modifying.

So "The button (that **is**) on the bottom right, **labelled** "blue" **is** red." should be translated 右下に**ある**「blue」と**付けられた**ボタンは赤い**です**。

Comment: I see. Just to make sure with a longer sentence, "The shiny, red button labeled 'blue' at the lower right is beautiful." would be キラキラしてる赤くて右下にある「blue」と付けられたボタンは美しいです。, right?

Comment: @DenisLi Right except the order. Japanese has implicit adjective order which is often the reverse of that in English. So 右下にある「blue」と付けられた赤くてキラキラしてるボタンは美しいです。 but more naturally IMO 右下にある「blue」と書かれた赤いキラキラしたボタンはきれいです。

Comment: @broccoliforest Thanks for the clarification. But is there a reason why you use 赤い instead of 赤くて in your second example? The way I know it would use 赤くて.

Comment: @DenisLi I don't have a definite answer, but in this context it will kind of sound as if you're saying "shiny **and** red" (or "red and shiny").